# Converting DTM data to STL?

Tags: dem, 3d, maps, stl

I'm new here and was wondering if anyone could help?
I'm looking to make some 3D maps using DTM data but need to convert it into .STL format for my MasterCAM to read so that I can generate the CAD files needed.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

QGIS does a direct conversion and is free.

1. Install QGIS
2. Instal [this](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DEMto3D/) plug in.
3. You can know just save as STL

As always you'll need some knowledge about STL format as you have many options to navigate.

Comment: Good example at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/229242/10229